# Записать в файл строки

Tags: pascal, сортировка, freepascal, файлы

```
const
    n=5;
    m=11;

input = 'input.txt';
output = 'output.txt';
type
    q=array [1..n,1..m] of char;
var
    ifile,ofile:text;
    mas:q;
    c:char;
    s,k,maxi,max,ch,i,j,ii,iii,iiii,jj:integer;

begin
    assign(ifile,input);
    reset(ifile);
    i:=1;
    while not eof(ifile) do begin
    j:=1;
        while not eoln(ifile) do begin
        {чтение=строка.новый символа строка.новый символ}
        read(ifile,mas[i,j]);
        j:=j+1;
        end;
    {Переход на индекс новой строки и чтение}
    readln(ifile);
    i:=i+1;
    end;close(ifile);

    writeln('ishodnii file:');
    for ii:=1 to n do begin
        for jj:=1 to m do 
        write(mas[ii,jj]);
        writeln;

        end;
                        for iii:=1 to 3 do 
                        for ii:=1 to n-1 do begin   
                            s:=8;
                            while (mas[ii,s]=mas[ii+1,s]) and (s<=m)
                             do  s:=s+1;
                             writeln(mas[ii,s]);
                                if(mas[ii,s]>mas[ii+1,s]) and (s<=m) then

                                    for k:=1 to m do begin
                                    c:=mas[ii,k];
                                    mas[ii,k]:=mas[ii+1,k];
                                    mas[ii+1,k]:=c;
                                    end;
                                    end;

            assign(ofile,output);
    reset(ofile);
    rewrite(ofile);
                for max:=n downto n-2 do
                        begin 
                        FOR k:=1 to m do 
                        write(mas[max,k]);
                        write(ofile,mas[max,k]);
                        writeln;
                        end; 
        end.
```

почему не срабатывает

> write(ofile,mas[max,k]);

Comment: Подсказка - решение в лоб - отсортировать все, и потом взять первые (или последние, в зависимости от направления сортировки) три.

Решение 2). выборка на лету. Представьте, что у Вас есть корзина с яблоками и нужно найти три самых больших (для замеров есть линейка). Вы берете первые три, а дальше, пока будут яблоки, берете очередное и меряете с этими тремя. Находите наименьшее и выбрасываете его.

Comment: i,j,ii,iii,iiii,jj - нужно больше i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const
    n=5;
    m=11;

input = 'input.txt';
output = 'output.txt';
type
    q=array [1..n,1..m] of char;
var
    ifile,ofile:text;
    mas:q;
    c:char;
    s,k,maxi,max,ch,i,j,ii,iii,iiii,jj:integer;

begin
    assign(ifile,input);
    reset(ifile);
    i:=1;
    while not eof(ifile) do begin
    j:=1;
        while not eoln(ifile) do begin
        {чтение=строка.новый символа строка.новый символ}
        read(ifile,mas[i,j]);
        j:=j+1;
        end;
    {Переход на индекс новой строки и чтение}
    readln(ifile);
    i:=i+1;
    end;close(ifile);
    writeln('ishodnii file:');
    for ii:=1 to n do begin
        for jj:=1 to m do 
        write(mas[ii,jj]);
        writeln;

        end;
                        for iii:=1 to 3 do 
                        for ii:=1 to n-1 do begin   
                            s:=8;
                            while (mas[ii,s]=mas[ii+1,s]) and (s<=m)
                             do  s:=s+1;
                             writeln(mas[ii,s]);
                                if(mas[ii,s]>mas[ii+1,s]) and (s<=m) then

                                    for k:=1 to m do begin
                                    c:=mas[ii,k];
                                    mas[ii,k]:=mas[ii+1,k];
                                    mas[ii+1,k]:=c;
                                    end;
                                    end;
                        for max:=n downto n-2 do
                        begin 
                        FOR k:=1 to m do
                        write(mas[max,k]);
                        writeln;
                        end; 
        end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Цикл по поиску максимального элемента запустить три раза. При поиске запоминать не только значение, но и индекс найденного максимального элемента. По окончании каждого из трёх циклов максимальному элементу присваивать какое-нибудь очень маленькое значение (заведомо меньшее остальных элементов, например, 0).

Другой вариант: отсортировать массив по убыванию и выбрать три первых элемента.

Заметте, приведённый вами код решает совершенно другую задачу (причём, судя по комментариям к нему, он это делает неправильно). Лучше переписать его с нуля. Я (да и никто на этом ресурсе) делать это за вас не стану.